# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel

Tags: flutter, file, path

for this code
Future get mylocalPath async {
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

```
return directory.path;
```

}

I tried
flutter clean
flutter pub get
outgrade etc
restrat

but no solve

For reading and writing in file, i need the path location

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99155#issuecomment-1052023743)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please close the current app and re-run the app

Comment: I have done it more than 3 times

Comment: Could you give me some insights into the code?

Comment: I have tried different way using cache manager package. now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Close the application and open it again, this problem happens when you add packages that need to be initialized when the application is compiled for the first time.
Hope this helps